# How can I check whether a subview exists at a certain frame in UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, subview

I have a UIScrollView with a big contentSize of around 5000*5000. I have the coordinates and the frame of a subview. I want to check whether a subview exists at that exact position in UIScrollView.

If no. I will add a new subView and if Yes I will not add. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[theScrollView hitTest:thePoint withEvent:nil];
```

will return the deepest CALayer at that point. If you are sure the point is within the UIScrollView, then if hitTest: returns the UIScrollView's CALayer, no subview exists at that point.

Answer (score 0):

```
 [theScrollView hitTest:thePoint withEvent:nil];
```